# How to do multicall in Solidity with abi.encodeWIthSelector with parameters?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin

Need help. I got the following error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'multi call failed'
    at RoleMultiCall.multiCall (contracts/optional/RoleMultiCall.sol:21)
    at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (/Users/azlan/projects/hardhats/dao-mix/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1772:23)
    at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (/Users/azlan/projects/hardhats/dao-mix/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:466:16)
    at async EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (/Users/azlan/projects/hardhats/dao-mix/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1496:18)
    at async HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/Users/azlan/projects/hardhats/dao-mix/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:118:18)
    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/azlan/projects/hardhats/dao-mix/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

when execute the following codes in a Hardhat task:

```
  const targets = [timeLockContract.address, timeLockContract.address];

  const encodedFunctions = [
    await timeLockContract.getDataGrantProposerRole(governorContract.address),
    await timeLockContract.getDataGrantExecutorRole(governorContract.address),
  ];

  const multiCallResult = await roleMultiCall.multiCall(
    targets,
    encodedFunctions,
  );
```

multi call contract :

```
contract RoleMultiCall {
  function multiCall(
    address[] calldata targets,
    bytes[] calldata encodedFunctions
  ) external returns (bytes[] memory) {
    ...
    for (uint256 i; i < targets.length; i++) {
      (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(targets[i]).call(
        encodedFunctions[i]
      );
      require(success, 'multi call failed');
      results[i] = result;
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

contract that uses abi.encodeWithSelector:

```
contract GovernanceTimeLock is TimelockController {
  ...

  function getDataGrantProposerRole(address account)
    external
    view
    returns (bytes memory)
  {
    return
      abi.encodeWithSelector(
        this.grantRole.selector,
        this.PROPOSER_ROLE,
        account
      );
  }
  function getDataGrantExecutorRole(address account) external view 
    returns (bytes memory) 
  { 
      //similar to function above
  }
```

Its all here https://github.com/azizazlan/dao-mix/tree/feature/multi-call-roles

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the `RoleMultiCall` contract must be granted the `TIMELOCK_ADMIN_ROLE` role.

So in the Hardhat task:

```
  ...

  await timeLockContract.grant( 
    await timeLockContract.TIMELOCK_ADMIN_ROLE(), 
    roleMultiCall.address);

  const multiCallResult = await roleMultiCall.multiCall(
    targets,
    encodedFunctions,
  );
```